# timeDate's isHoliday not working with vector of dates

Tags: r

I have two date columns and I need to create a new column with the number of non holidays and non weekends between the two dates for each row.

Using the timeDate package's isHoliday gives me the correct output on a per row basis, but when I apply the same approach using vectorized columns, I get the following error. I understand the error, but how can I supply a vector as input to get my desired output?

```
> library(timeDate)
> d1
    sendDate postingDate
1 2014-07-03  2014-07-03
2 2014-07-03  2014-07-03
3 2014-07-03  2014-07-03
4 2014-07-03  2014-07-03
5 2014-07-03  2014-07-07
6 2014-07-03  2014-07-07
> d1$numBankDays <- sum(!isHoliday(timeSequence(d1$sendDate, d1$postingDate, 'day')))
Error in seq.timeDate(from = from, to = to, by = by) : 
  'from' must be of length 1
```

Looping through each row like this and computing the desired value works, but I don't want to loop through million(s) of rows. Is there a proper solution?

```
> for (i in 1:nrow(d1)) {d1$numBankDays[i] <- sum(!isHoliday(timeSequence(d1$sendDate[i], d1$postingDate[i], 'day')))}
> d1
    sendDate postingDate numBankDays
1 2014-07-03  2014-07-03           1
2 2014-07-03  2014-07-03           1
3 2014-07-03  2014-07-03           1
4 2014-07-03  2014-07-03           1
5 2014-07-03  2014-07-07           3
6 2014-07-03  2014-07-07           3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `apply`:

```
d1$days <- apply(d1, 1, function(x){sum(!isHoliday(timeSequence(x[1], x[2], 'day')))})
```

EDIT: it seems that the function `isHoliday` generates holidays only for the current year, and is slow and called every time you run it. The comparison in `isHoliday` is also really slow

let's make our own list of holidays using the function they call each time so we only have to call it once (make sure the years cover your whole data range):

```
allholidays <- as.character(as.Date(holidayNYSE(2014:2015), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Now let's make a better function:

```
isworkdayfunction <- function(df){
  x <- seq(from = as.Date(df[1]), to = as.Date(df[2]), by = "day")
  sum(!(x[isWeekday(x)] %in% allholidays))
}
```

Now we can use apply:

```
d1$numBankDays <- apply(d1, 1, isworkdayfunction)
```

Finally, let's time the three versions:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(original=for (i in 1:nrow(d1)) {d1$numBankDays[i] <- sum(!isHoliday(timeSequence(d1$sendDate[i], d1$postingDate[i], 'day')))},
               apply1 = apply(d1, 1, function(x){sum(!isHoliday(timeSequence(x[1], x[2], 'day')))}),
               newapply = apply(d1,1,isworkdayfunction)
               )

Unit: milliseconds
     expr       min         lq       mean    median         uq        max neval
 original 261.73945 267.584458 272.775199 270.54949 276.327679 305.155272   100
   apply1 265.33750 269.710072 278.228613 272.45411 277.532853 446.030608   100
 newapply   3.21943   3.334436   3.432978   3.38762   3.426595   6.440394   100
```

So it's about 100 times faster now

Comment: Isn't that just a wrapper that invokes the function per row? Takes forever. My table has over million rows.

Comment: it will be faster, as the loop part is in general slow. However in this case you actual functions are very slow, so the speed up is small. I'll take a look at the functions now

Comment: Fantastic. I was working on a not so clean approach by creating a matrix of all possible day windows in my entire date range that I can index into for each call to the function. This seems cleaner. Will benchmark both of them though now that I am curious.